# Can get combined tuple tensor using tf.concat?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm apparently novice to tensorflow and trying to make new tensor using two existing tensors.

Let's say there are two tensors t1 and t2.

```
t1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
t2 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Is there anyway I can get new tensor t3 shaped like as following using tf.concat?

```
t3 = [(1,7),(2,8),(3,9),(4,10),(5,11),(6,12)]
```

So the first item in the first tensor combined with the first item in the second tensor and converted combined item as a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) instead?

```
tf.stack((t1, t2), axis=1)
```

If you're set on using `tf.concat`, you could expand to an extra dimension ahead of time?

```
tf.concat((tf.expand_dims(t1, 1), tf.expand_dims(t2, 1)), axis=1)
```

But `tf.stack` is quite a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you so much, James! tf.stack meets my needs. Now I'm very close to the destination, but tf.stack returns np.ndarray rather than tuple. Any idea on this? Thank you again!

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize you wanted tuples. I don't think you can have a tensor of tuples. You could have Python list of tuples? That would be as easy as `list(zip(t1, t2))`